# Is there a way to add clickable hyperlinks to an excel chart's data labels?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to make it so when I click on a data label on the chart, I am hyperlinked to a related sheet in the workbook.

[Here is a section of the chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQB58.png)   The goal is to be able to click "CSC - RCN" for instance (the label on the bar, not the axis label), and then be hyperlinked to the CSC-RCN sheet of the workbook.

I've tried achieving this with Chart Events like this:

```
Sub Charts_BeforeDoubleClick()

     If Charts("Chart 1").ElementID = "xlDataLabel" Then

          If Arg1 = "Duration" Then

               If Arg2 = "CSC - RCN" Then
               Worksheets("TIMELINE DATA SHEET").Range("A3").Hyperlinks(1).Follow
               End If

          End If

     End If

End Sub
```

But I guess I don't know enough about how this works. Am I on the right track? Is there a better way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

[Here is the VBA code I landed on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tIVI.png)

Comment: could you copy and paste the code please?

Comment: @MacroMarc is right. Both questions and answers need to include actual code in text, [not screenshots of code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3025856). That makes the information more readable—and accessible!—and easier for future readers to copy and paste. Answers that rely primarily on a screenshot of code may be subject to deletion.

Comment: you won't learn anything if you just copy and paste all your life.